# "invalid json-primitive" when converting JSON string

Tags: json, powershell

I've seen many posts with this error, but nothing helps me out.
so here is my situation:

the json is created by jquery like this:

```
json_zug_grp = [];
$('#bx_zuggrp:checked').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).val();
    item = {}
    item ["name"] = name;
    item ["value"] = value;
    json_zug_grp.push(item);
});
```

After this, i make an ajax call to a php script, with this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'psexec.php',
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data:{    
          zug_grps:JSON.stringify(json_zug_grp)
     },
     success: function(text){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(json_zug_grp));
    }   
});
```

The console.log gives me the output WITH quotes.

```
 [{"name":"USB_R","value":"CN=USB_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc"},{"name":"DVD_R","value":"CN=DVD_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc"}]
```

And finaly the php-script makes a shell_exec from the ps-script with the json string as parameter:

```
$zug_grps = $_POST["zug_grps"];
$para = " -zug_grps '".$zug_grps."'";
$psPath = "powershell.exe";
$psDIR = "C:\\path\\to\\scriptfolder\\";
$psScript = "script.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript." ".$para; 
$output = shell_exec($runCMD);
echo $output;
```

Also this echo gives the json-string WITH quotes.

script.ps1 looks like this:

```
 param(  
        [string]$zug_grps
    )

`Write-Host $zug_grps`
```

The output looks like this:

```
[{name:USB_R,value:CN=USB_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc},{name:DVD_R,value:CN=DVD_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc}]
```

don´t know why the quotes in ps are eliminated.

Now if I convert the string like this:

```
$parsed = $zug_grps | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I get the following error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON-primitive: USB_R.

Any idea, what goes wrong?

Comment: I'd say that should work, but try `$para = ' -zug_grps "'.addslashes($zug_grps).'"';`, just for good measure.

Comment: this does the magic! now the quotes are within the string, and all works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JSON must be in double quotes, so the data must look like what you first posted:

```
[{"name":"USB_R","value":"CN=USB_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc"},{"name":"DVD_R","value":"CN=DVD_R,OU=ZuGrp,OU=SecGrp,DC=DOMAIN,DC=loc"}]
```

---

**Edit:** Apparently PHP does funky things with the JSON string¹, so putting a string with double quotes between single quotes like this doesn't work:

```php
$para = " -zug_grps '".$zug_grps."'";
```

Escaping the double quotes in the JSON string and putting the escaped string between double quotes seems to work, though:

```php
$para = ' -zug_grps "'.addslashes($zug_grps).'"';
```

¹ FTR: I am somewhat less than surprised.

Comment: thanks. the quotes are in the original json-string. when i "Write-Host " the string from the script, there aren´t quotes. Is this because of a formating inside the powershell?

Comment: If they were in the string `Write-Host` would display them. How is the original string created and how exactly is the script called?